# horizontal timeline fixed distance and centered on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, timeline

I am trying to reach a horizontal timeline like this:
https://codepen.io/ritz078/pen/LGRWjE

My problem is, that I've got no real dates (DD/MM/YYYY) but only years like 1998-2002 or just 2009. So there is a problem, I am struggling to fix, which ends up like this:

[image]

So my aims are:

1. Set a fixed distance between elements
2. Make it work just with years
3. When on a device less than 768px wide ensure a single element is displayed and it appears in the center

This is my solution for 3., but the other things, I couldnt solute:

```
if ($(window).width() < 768 {
    eventsMinDistance = $('.cd-horizontal-timeline .events-wrapper').width(/2;)
}

(timelines.length > 0) && initTimeline(timelines);

$(window).resize(function(){
    if ($(window).width() < 768 {
    eventsMinDistance = $('.cd-horizontal-timeline .events-wrapper').width(/2;)
    } else{
        eventsMinDistance = 155;
    }
}
```

Do you guys know how do adjust it, as I am struggling since hours without any success. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 3):

the first part of your code works fine, but it was faulty on the syntax, I fixed it and use it and also add a couple of changes to acomplished the desired fixed width amount between each date.
Actually it was pretty easy, when you debug and you know exactly what the developer wants to do.
This is the code I wrote:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var timelines = $('.cd-horizontal-timeline'),
        eventsRelativeDistance = false;
    if ($(window).width() < 768) {
        eventsMinDistance = Number($('.cd-horizontal-timeline .events-wrapper').width())/2;
    }else{
        var eventsMinDistance = 100;
    }

    (timelines.length > 0) && initTimeline(timelines);

    $(window).resize( function(){
        if ($(window).width() < 768) {
            eventsMinDistance = Number($('.cd-horizontal-timeline .events-wrapper').width())/2;
        } else{
            eventsMinDistance = 100;
        }
    });

    function initTimeline(timelines) {
        timelines.each(function(){
            var timeline = $(this),
                timelineComponents = {};
            //cache timeline components
            timelineComponents['timelineWrapper'] = timeline.find('.events-wrapper');
            timelineComponents['eventsWrapper'] = timelineComponents['timelineWrapper'].children('.events');
            timelineComponents['fillingLine'] = timelineComponents['eventsWrapper'].children('.filling-line');
            timelineComponents['timelineEvents'] = timelineComponents['eventsWrapper'].find('a');
            timelineComponents['timelineDates'] = parseDate(timelineComponents['timelineEvents']);
            timelineComponents['eventsMinLapse'] = minLapse(timelineComponents['timelineDates']);
            timelineComponents['timelineNavigation'] = timeline.find('.cd-timeline-navigation');
            timelineComponents['eventsContent'] = timeline.children('.events-content');
            if(!eventsRelativeDistance){
                // Set up space to store the distance in pixels.
                timelineComponents['distanceInPx'] = [];
            }

            //assign a left postion to the single events along the timeline
            setDatePosition(timelineComponents, eventsMinDistance, eventsRelativeDistance);
            //assign a width to the timeline
            var timelineTotWidth = setTimelineWidth(timelineComponents, eventsMinDistance, eventsRelativeDistance);
            //the timeline has been initialize - show it
            timeline.addClass('loaded');

            //detect click on the next arrow
            timelineComponents['timelineNavigation'].on('click', '.next', function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                updateSlide(timelineComponents, timelineTotWidth, 'next');
            });
            //detect click on the prev arrow
            timelineComponents['timelineNavigation'].on('click', '.prev', function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                updateSlide(timelineComponents, timelineTotWidth, 'prev');
            });
            //detect click on the a single gallery - show new gallery content
            timelineComponents['eventsWrapper'].on('click', 'a', function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                timelineComponents['timelineEvents'].removeClass('selected');
                $(this).addClass('selected');
                updateOlderEvents($(this));
                updateFilling($(this), timelineComponents['fillingLine'], timelineTotWidth);
                updateVisibleContent($(this), timelineComponents['eventsContent']);
            });

            //on swipe, show next/prev gallery content
            timelineComponents['eventsContent'].on('swipeleft', function(){
                var mq = checkMQ();
                ( mq == 'mobile' ) && showNewContent(timelineComponents, timelineTotWidth, 'next');
            });
            timelineComponents['eventsContent'].on('swiperight', function(){
                var mq = checkMQ();
                ( mq == 'mobile' ) && showNewContent(timelineComponents, timelineTotWidth, 'prev');
            });

            //keyboard navigation
            $(document).keyup(function(event){
                if(event.which=='37' && elementInViewport(timeline.get(0)) ) {
                    showNewContent(timelineComponents, timelineTotWidth, 'prev');
                } else if( event.which=='39' && elementInViewport(timeline.get(0))) {
                    showNewContent(timelineComponents, timelineTotWidth, 'next');
                }
            });
        });
    }

    function updateSlide(timelineComponents, timelineTotWidth, string) {
        //retrieve translateX value of timelineComponents['eventsWrapper']
        var translateValue = getTranslateValue(timelineComponents['eventsWrapper']),
            wrapperWidth = Number(timelineComponents['timelineWrapper'].css('width').replace('px', ''));
        //translate the timeline to the left('next')/right('prev')
        (string == 'next')
            ? translateTimeline(timelineComponents, translateValue - wrapperWidth + eventsMinDistance, wrapperWidth - timelineTotWidth)
            : translateTimeline(timelineComponents, translateValue + wrapperWidth - eventsMinDistance);
    }

    function showNewContent(timelineComponents, timelineTotWidth, string) {
        //go from one gallery to the next/previous one
        var visibleContent =  timelineComponents['eventsContent'].find('.selected'),
            newContent = ( string == 'next' ) ? visibleContent.next() : visibleContent.prev();

        if ( newContent.length > 0 ) { //if there's a next/prev gallery - show it
            var selectedDate = timelineComponents['eventsWrapper'].find('.selected'),
                newEvent = ( string == 'next' ) ? selectedDate.parent('li').next('li').children('a') : selectedDate.parent('li').prev('li').children('a');

            updateFilling(newEvent, timelineComponents['fillingLine'], timelineTotWidth);
            updateVisibleContent(newEvent, timelineComponents['eventsContent']);
            newEvent.addClass('selected');
            selectedDate.removeClass('selected');
            updateOlderEvents(newEvent);
            updateTimelinePosition(string, newEvent, timelineComponents);
        }
    }

    function updateTimelinePosition(string, event, timelineComponents) {
        //translate timeline to the left/right according to the position of the selected gallery
        var eventStyle = window.getComputedStyle(event.get(0), null),
            eventLeft = Number(eventStyle.getPropertyValue("left").replace('px', '')),
            timelineWidth = Number(timelineComponents['timelineWrapper'].css('width').replace('px', '')),
            timelineTotWidth = Number(timelineComponents['eventsWrapper'].css('width').replace('px', ''));
        var timelineTranslate = getTranslateValue(timelineComponents['eventsWrapper']);

        if( (string == 'next' && eventLeft > timelineWidth - timelineTranslate) || (string == 'prev' && eventLeft < - timelineTranslate) ) {
            translateTimeline(timelineComponents, - eventLeft + timelineWidth/2, timelineWidth - timelineTotWidth);
        }
    }

    function translateTimeline(timelineComponents, value, totWidth) {
        var eventsWrapper = timelineComponents['eventsWrapper'].get(0);
        value = (value > 0) ? 0 : value; //only negative translate value
        value = ( !(typeof totWidth === 'undefined') &&  value < totWidth ) ? totWidth : value; //do not translate more than timeline width
        setTransformValue(eventsWrapper, 'translateX', value+'px');
        //update navigation arrows visibility
        (value == 0 ) ? timelineComponents['timelineNavigation'].find('.prev').addClass('inactive') : timelineComponents['timelineNavigation'].find('.prev').removeClass('inactive');
        (value == totWidth ) ? timelineComponents['timelineNavigation'].find('.next').addClass('inactive') : timelineComponents['timelineNavigation'].find('.next').removeClass('inactive');
    }

    function updateFilling(selectedEvent, filling, totWidth) {
        //change .filling-line length according to the selected gallery
        var eventStyle = window.getComputedStyle(selectedEvent.get(0), null),
            eventLeft = eventStyle.getPropertyValue("left"),
            eventWidth = eventStyle.getPropertyValue("width");
        eventLeft = Number(eventLeft.replace('px', '')) + Number(eventWidth.replace('px', ''))/2;
        var scaleValue = eventLeft/totWidth;
        setTransformValue(filling.get(0), 'scaleX', scaleValue);
    }

    function setDatePosition(timelineComponents, min, relativeDistance) {
        var distance,
            distanceNorm = 0,
            distancesInPx =[];
        for (i = 0; i < timelineComponents['timelineDates'].length; i++) {
            if (relativeDistance){
                distance = daydiff(timelineComponents['timelineDates'][0], timelineComponents['timelineDates'][i]);
                distanceNorm = Math.round(distance/timelineComponents['eventsMinLapse']) + 2;
            }else{
                distance = 5;
                distanceNorm = Math.round(distance/timelineComponents['eventsMinLapse']) + 2 + distanceNorm;
                // Save am array of sizes to track the distance in pixels from the left.
                timelineComponents['distanceInPx'].push(distanceNorm*min);
            }
            timelineComponents['timelineEvents'].eq(i).css('left', distanceNorm*min+'px');
        }
    }

    function setTimelineWidth(timelineComponents, width, relativeDistance) {
        var timeSpan = 0, timeSpanNorm, totalWidth;
        if(relativeDistance){
            // If relative Time Distance daydiff caclulates the first date and the last one.
            timeSpan = daydiff(timelineComponents['timelineDates'][0], timelineComponents['timelineDates'][timelineComponents['timelineDates'].length-1]);
            timeSpanNorm = timeSpan/timelineComponents['eventsMinLapse'];
                timeSpanNorm = Math.round(timeSpanNorm) + 4;
                totalWidth = timeSpanNorm*width;
        }else{
            // However if no relative Distance we obtain the amount of distance in pixels from the last position of the array which is the farthest element on the array.
            totalWidth = timelineComponents['distanceInPx'][timelineComponents['distanceInPx'].length-1];
        }
        timelineComponents['eventsWrapper'].css('width', totalWidth+'px');
        updateFilling(timelineComponents['eventsWrapper'].find('a.selected'), timelineComponents['fillingLine'], totalWidth);
        updateTimelinePosition('next', timelineComponents['eventsWrapper'].find('a.selected'), timelineComponents);

        return totalWidth;
    }

    function updateVisibleContent(event, eventsContent) {
        var eventDate = event.data('date'),
            visibleContent = eventsContent.find('.selected'),
            selectedContent = eventsContent.find('[data-date="'+ eventDate +'"]'),
            selectedContentHeight = selectedContent.height();

        if (selectedContent.index() > visibleContent.index()) {
            var classEnetering = 'selected enter-right',
                classLeaving = 'leave-left';
        } else {
            var classEnetering = 'selected enter-left',
                classLeaving = 'leave-right';
        }

        selectedContent.attr('class', classEnetering);
        visibleContent.attr('class', classLeaving).one('webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend msAnimationEnd animationend', function(){
            visibleContent.removeClass('leave-right leave-left');
            selectedContent.removeClass('enter-left enter-right');
        });
        eventsContent.css('height', selectedContentHeight+'px');
    }

    function updateOlderEvents(event) {
        event.parent('li').prevAll('li').children('a').addClass('older-gallery').end().end().nextAll('li').children('a').removeClass('older-gallery');
    }

    function getTranslateValue(timeline) {
        var timelineStyle = window.getComputedStyle(timeline.get(0), null),
            timelineTranslate = timelineStyle.getPropertyValue("-webkit-transform") ||
                timelineStyle.getPropertyValue("-moz-transform") ||
                timelineStyle.getPropertyValue("-ms-transform") ||
                timelineStyle.getPropertyValue("-o-transform") ||
                timelineStyle.getPropertyValue("transform");

        if( timelineTranslate.indexOf('(') >=0 ) {
            var timelineTranslate = timelineTranslate.split('(')[1];
            timelineTranslate = timelineTranslate.split(')')[0];
            timelineTranslate = timelineTranslate.split(',');
            var translateValue = timelineTranslate[4];
        } else {
            var translateValue = 0;
        }

        return Number(translateValue);
    }

    function setTransformValue(element, property, value) {
        element.style["-webkit-transform"] = property+"("+value+")";
        element.style["-moz-transform"] = property+"("+value+")";
        element.style["-ms-transform"] = property+"("+value+")";
        element.style["-o-transform"] = property+"("+value+")";
        element.style["transform"] = property+"("+value+")";
    }

    //based on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/542938/how-do-i-get-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates-in-javascript
    function parseDate(events) {
        var dateArrays = [];
        events.each(function(){
            var singleDate = $(this),
                dateComp = singleDate.data('date').split('T');
            if( dateComp.length > 1 ) { //both DD/MM/YEAR and time are provided
                var dayComp = dateComp[0].split('/'),
                    timeComp = dateComp[1].split(':');
            } else if( dateComp[0].indexOf(':') >=0 ) { //only time is provide
                var dayComp = ["2000", "0", "0"],
                    timeComp = dateComp[0].split(':');
            } else { //only DD/MM/YEAR
                var dayComp = dateComp[0].split('/'),
                    timeComp = ["0", "0"];
            }
            var newDate = new Date(dayComp[2], dayComp[1]-1, dayComp[0], timeComp[0], timeComp[1]);
            dateArrays.push(newDate);
        });
        return dateArrays;
    }

    function daydiff(first, second) {
        return Math.round((second-first));
    }

    function minLapse(dates) {
        //determine the minimum distance among events
        var dateDistances = [];
        for (i = 1; i < dates.length; i++) {
            var distance = daydiff(dates[i-1], dates[i]);
            dateDistances.push(distance);
        }
        return Math.min.apply(null, dateDistances);
    }

    /*
        How to tell if a DOM element is visible in the current viewport?
        http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123999/how-to-tell-if-a-dom-element-is-visible-in-the-current-viewport
    */
    function elementInViewport(el) {
        var top = el.offsetTop;
        var left = el.offsetLeft;
        var width = el.offsetWidth;
        var height = el.offsetHeight;

        while(el.offsetParent) {
            el = el.offsetParent;
            top += el.offsetTop;
            left += el.offsetLeft;
        }

        return (
            top < (window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight) &&
            left < (window.pageXOffset + window.innerWidth) &&
            (top + height) > window.pageYOffset &&
            (left + width) > window.pageXOffset
        );
    }

    function checkMQ() {
        //check if mobile or desktop device
        return window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('.cd-horizontal-timeline'), '::before').getPropertyValue('content').replace(/'/g, "").replace(/"/g, "");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever get this to work?? Have come across the same problem. If i change the default distance from 60 to 1 the gap between is not enough and the whole timeline breaks. The calculations for the distance as described in the article is as follows

> First of all, in the main.js file, we set a minimum distance between two consecutive dates, using the eventsMinDistance variable; in our case, we set eventsMinDistance = 60 (so the minimum distance will be 60px). Then we evaluate all the differences between a date and the following one; to do that we use the data-date attribute added to each date. The minimum difference is then used as a reference to evaluate the distances between two consecutive dates.
>
> For example, let's suppose the minimum found difference is 5 days; that means that the distance, along the timeline, between two dates separated by a lapse of 5days will  be 60px, while the one between two events separated by a lapse of 10 days will be 120px.

[source:: www.codyhouse.org](https://codyhouse.co/gem/horizontal-timeline)

From what i read the min distance is here:~

```
var timelines = $('.cd-horizontal-timeline'),
    eventsMinDistance = 60;

(timelines.length > 0) && initTimeline(timelines);
```

This creates a variable called timelines and sets it to the class .cd-hor... and sets the min distance to 60px. changing this to 1 breaks the application as the distance between the times are too small.

```
function setDatePosition(timelineComponents, min) {
    for (i = 0; i < timelineComponents['timelineDates'].length; i++) {
        var distance = daydiff(timelineComponents['timelineDates'][0], timelineComponents['timelineDates'][i]),
            distanceNorm = Math.round(distance/timelineComponents['eventsMinLapse']) + 2;
        timelineComponents['timelineEvents'].eq(i).css('left', distanceNorm*min+'px');
    }
}
```

I might be wrong but here is the section calculating the distance and the last distanceNorm*min+'px'. min i believe is 60 and distance norm is the calculation of the 5 days etc. if you remove distance norm the app breaks so you cant just add min+'px' this is because you remove the original distance.

All distances are calculated from the first timeline. Thats why the app breaks. Need to find the code that tells which to calc from which is the

```
var distance = daydiff(timelineComponents['timelineDates'][0], timelineComponents['timelineDates'][i]),
            distanceNorm = Math.round(distance/timelineComponents['eventsMinLapse']) + 2;
```

this sets distance as the first element of the index and then for each timelineDates within the loop [i].

I've been at it for days but have come to the conclusion the tutorial is good as is but it is not a library and should be used as reference to write your own from scratch which is what i am now doing.

If you did ever manage it though please update as so far i managed to manipulate the dates to get equal spacing but if you insert too many it breaks which is no good hence the rewrite!

Comment: If you have a question, and the answers here do not help to resolve it, please use the Ask Question feature. You can always link back to this question if it's relevant. You have posted this in the Answers section, but it does not answer the question above.

Comment: i know it doesnt answer but maybe the original poster found the answer so i asked. it wouldnt fit in a comment. Not a single person answered his question why would they answer mine instead this community seems to just nit pick at everyone trying to learn. Its funny how a topic over a year old got no help but my comment sure drove out those internet warriors. Brilliant that such a wonderful community of people pointing out faults rather than helping.